# dismiss modalviewcontroller from another modalviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, modalviewcontroller

I am presenting a modalviewcontroller from another modalviewcontroller. When I dismiss the second modalviewcontroller both the first and second modalviewcontroller should get dismissed. I tried to access the first modalview like

```
[self.view.superview dismissmodalviewcontroller];
```

but it is showing error. What is the right way to get a ref to the first modalViewController from the second one and invoke the dismiss method from it?

Comment: After having asked 25 questions already I think you should learn how to format correctly on StackOverflow. If you format your question so that it's easier to read people are more inclined to read and answer it.

Comment: when you write question select whole code part using mouse, and click '{}' button at the top..That is the way to format codes..

Comment: thanks will keep that in future...btw i am still stuck.somebody out there pls help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its like this.

A presents B. Here, A is parent of B (Here, A.modalViewController will be B and B.parentViewController will be A)

And B presents C. Here, B is parent of C (Here, B.modalViewController will be C and C.parentViewController will be B)

According to apple guidelines, its responsibility of parent controller to dismiss its child controller.

So if you want to dismiss controller C, you call dismissModalViewController at C.parentViewController. As C's parent is B, thus B is dismissing its modal (child) controller that it presented.

But you want to even dismiss B. Its responsibility of B's parent to dismiss B. So you need to say [B.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];

Thus, you need to get B from C as C.parentViewController (Don't forget to typecast here). Then you say that [B.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];

Answer (score 2):

Try `[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

This will dismiss both modal view controllers

Comment: i tried it this way.but this does not seems to work.this is the hierarchy of views.tableviewcontroller->modalviewcontroller->modalviewcontroller

Answer (score 2):

The [dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissModalViewControllerAnimated%3a) method is part of the `UIViewController` class, not the of `UIView`. So you need to do

```
[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

instead of calling it on `self.view.superview`.

Comment: this is not working tried to do like this but only one view is being dismissed.the first modalview is not going.is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @sujith1406: So you should have a `[self dismissModelViewControllerAnimated:YES];` already. Try replacing it with `[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` instead. From the linked documentation: *If you present several modal view controllers in succession, and thus build a stack of modal view controllers, calling this method on a view controller lower in the stack dismisses its immediate child view controller and all view controllers above that child on the stack.*.

Comment: sorry to trouble you again,when i got ur answer i first replaced [self dismissModelViewControllerAnimated:YES]; with [self.parentViewController dismissModelViewControllerAnimated:YES]; but in both cases only the second modalview is being dismissed.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify even further, what you will probably need is something like this:

```
[self.parentViewController.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

i just found it's answer, may be it will help somebody 
we need just one line of code

```
[self.presentingViewController.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly it the view always flick to the first modal in the stack then perform the animation.

I fixed it with a custom animation:

```
        let transition: CATransition = CATransition()
        transition.duration = 0.5
        transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
        transition.type = kCATransitionReveal
        transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom
        self.view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: nil)
        self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```