# Crashing after dismissing a Modal View Controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

Im presenting and dismissing a Modal View Controller. I use delegation so I dismiss the modalView at the Parent.

```
- (void)launchDrawingSection{

    drawingSectionViewController = [[DrawingSectionViewController alloc] init];
    drawingSectionViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft;
    drawingSectionViewController.drawingModalDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:drawingSectionViewController animated:YES];
}


- (void)didDismissDrawingModalView{

    NSLog(@"didDismissDrawingModalView");
    [drawingSectionViewController release];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

The app crashes after the dealloc method in the ModalView gets called.

Am I doing something wrong with the way I present and dismiss a Modal View Controller? Any idea?

Comment: If it is crashing in the modal view controller's `dealloc`, you must probably be over releasing one of its instance variables. Any crash logs?

Comment: when does didDismissDrawingModalView method gets called?

Comment: It is called when I exit the ModalView. It is a Protocol method I use so the ParentView is the one that dismisses the modalview.

Comment: What do you mean by "exit" ModalView? The DrawingModalView was presented as a modal view controller. The only way it should exit is to "dismiss". As your function name "didDismissDrawingModalView" indicates that DrawingModalView already "did" dismiss, then why is it getting once again dismissed?

Comment: It is just a bad function name. In the ModalView I have a function named DismissView, which tells the Delegate(ParentView) function didDismissDrawingModalView to dismiss the View. So it is dismissed just once.

Answer (score 0):

Don't release before dismiss.

```
- (void)launchDrawingSection{

        drawingSectionViewController = [[DrawingSectionViewController alloc] init];

        drawingSectionViewController.modalTransitionStyle =          UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft;

        drawingSectionViewController.drawingModalDelegate = self;

        [self presentModalViewController:drawingSectionViewController animated:YES];

        [drawingSectionViewController release];    


}




- (void)didDismissDrawingModalView{
    NSLog(@"didDismissDrawingModalView");

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];


}
```

Comment: Not releasing it causes memory leak, isn't it? Where do I release it then? If I place it after the dismiss, it still crashes.

Comment: no we have released them immediately after presenting them so not leak there.

Comment: what happened please let me know if it has leak

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying that. After checking the dealloc function in the ModalView, I realized that some of the releases are causing the app to crash. Do you know if I must take care of the position of the releases? I mean, if I release an object that is used by another object released 2 or 3 lines below is a cause of crashing?

Comment: It is always best to release as soon as possible and no sooner.  In this case, your modal VC is retained by the system when you present it (and released by it when you dismiss it).  Therefore, as madhu says, you can release it right after the presentModalViewController call. In fact, it should be a local variable inside of launchDrawingSection.  However, as you found out, your original crash wasn't due to that, as your release in didDismiss was just delayed,not duplicated.

Comment: To answer your dealloc question, that depends on whether the "parent" object retains it or not.  If it does properly retain it, then releasing your controller's retain will only decrement the release count, but not to zero.  However if it is an assignment, not a retain, then yes, it can cause a crash. Simple rule: alloc, new, copy and retain (including retaining setters) all increment; release  decrements (and autorelease defers a decrement).

Answer (score 0):

Your fundamentals of Modal View Controller is not clear.
If you are using delegate protocols only to inform the drawing sections's parent control to dismiss the drawing section controller, then this is something useless. Because, the following thing does your job without use of delegates.

```
// Present drawing section.
- (void)launchDrawingSection{

    drawingSectionViewController = [[DrawingSectionViewController alloc] init];
    drawingSectionViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft;
    drawingSectionViewController.drawingModalDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:drawingSectionViewController animated:YES];
    [drawingSectionViewController release];
}

// (Put this in Drawing Section View Controller). This function dismisses drawing section.
- (void)dismissActionEvent{
    // Drawing section view controller is asking its parent to dismiss it.
    [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

To understand clearly how presenting and dismissing modal view controller's work, refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935462/dismiss-modalviewcontroller-from-another-modalviewcontroller/5936872#5936872)

Comment: I know how Modal View Controller works. I was using Apple's preferred technique to dismiss a ModalView which is Delegation. Let me tell you that I did not know there was a different way to dismiss. It is good to know some alternatives.

Comment: Well, although that does indeed work, Apple clearly differs with you:
 
"Although there are several techniques for notifying a parent view controller that it should dismiss its modally presented child, the preferred technique is delegation. ... This use of delegation to manage interactions with a modal view controller has some key advantages over other techniques:

The delegate object has the opportunity to validate or incorporate changes from the modal view controller before that view controller is dismissed. Second, the use of a delegate promotes better encapsulation..."

Comment: I agree with the "encapsulation" thing. Thanks. I learned something from here :)