# dismissModalViewController issue in iOs

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, navigation, presentmodalviewcontroller, dismiss

I have three view controllers, say A, B and C. I am navigating through this views like follows;

**A** -presenting-> **B** -presenting-> **C** -presenting-> **B**

And from **B**, if I dismiss I want to navigate to **C**. But instead of that, now it is moving to **A**. I can't use dismiss for navigation from **C** to **B** (some internal issues). So how can I fix this? Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5935462/dismiss-modalviewcontroller-from-another-modalviewcontroller And I am sure there are more...

Comment: I saw that post and tried to fix the issue, but still not working.

Comment: are you using the `UINavigationController` to navigate among the views?

Comment: No, i am not using UINavigationController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hit into a limitation of `dismissModalViewController`: it will remove all of your modal views ([source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissModalViewControllerAnimated%3a)):

> If you present several view controllers in succession, and thus build a stack of presented view controllers, calling this method on a view controller lower in the stack dismisses its immediate child view controller and all view controllers above that child on the stack. When this happens, only the top-most view is dismissed in an animated fashion; any intermediate view controllers are simply removed from the stack. The top-most view is dismissed using its modal transition style, which may differ from the styles used by other view controllers lower in the stack.

What you could do is using a `UINavigationController` and simply push/pop controllers on to it according to your requirements.

Alternatively, you could simply display the views managed by the various controllers you have by directly calling `addSubview` on your top view and making sure they cover the whole screen and that the managing controller is correctly retained/released (the view is automatically when you add/remove it to another view).

As a hint, you could do it like this:

1. where you have `presentModal...`, use `addSubview`;
2. where you have `dismiss...`, use `removeFromSuperview`;
3. store a reference to any view controller whose view you manage like I suggest here in `retain`/`strong` property.

Comment: I can't use navigation controller in this one. I have to use presenting and dismissing methods.

Comment: please, see my edit. in your case, the only way I see is manually doing `addSubview`/`removeFromSuperview` with your "modal" views.

Comment: I appreciate your help but now I can't use the above suggestion in my app right now, as I have almost completed all the works and few are remaining and got this error.

Comment: is there any way, if I keep an object of a parent viewcontroller and dismissing the view? I am not sure how to do this, but it just came up in my mind. Any idea?

Comment: I don't think you have any easy way to use modal view controllers. On the other hand, using addSubview/removeFromSuperview should be really straightforward and requires no big changes to your app.

Answer (score 0):

Hi use the below code in "C" viewcontroller

```
[[[self presentingViewController] presentingViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```